# c - Game of Life problem generating new board

Tags: c, conways-game-of-life

I'm trying to implement Game of Life in C. I'm certain I programmed the rules of the game correctly, but the cells do not update correctly when running the program. In the beginning of `main`, I hard-coded a glider onto the map, but it doesn't 'glide' southwest like it's supposed to. I think the source of the problem might be in the `update()` function, but I can't find it myself.

(This isn't homework, this is just a personal project.)

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX_Y 10 /* height */
#define MAX_X 30 /* width */

int neighbors(int grid[MAX_Y][MAX_X], int x, int y) {
   int dx, dy, dstx, dsty;
   int n = 0;

   for (dy = -1; dy < 2; ++dy) {
      for (dx = -1; dx < 2; ++dx) {
         dsty = y + dy;
         dstx = x + dx;

         if (dsty > 0 && dsty < MAX_Y && dstx > 0 && dstx < MAX_X) {
            n += !!grid[dsty][dstx]; /* use !! so that non-zero values eval to 1 */
         }
      }
   }
   /* (n > 0) ? printf("Point (%d,%d) has %d neighbors!\n", x, y, n) : 0; */
   return n;
}

int **update(int grid[MAX_Y][MAX_X]) {
   int new[MAX_Y][MAX_X];
   memset(new, 0, sizeof new);
   int i, j, n;

   for (i = 0; i < MAX_Y; ++i) {
      for (j = 0; j < MAX_X; ++j) {
         n = neighbors(grid, i, j);

         /* alive, 2 or 3 neighbors    -> alive!
          * dead, 3 neighbors          -> alive!
          * anything else              -> dead :(
          */

         if (grid[i][j] && (n == 2 || n == 3))
            new[i][j] = 1;
         else if (!grid[i][j] && n == 3)
            new[i][j] = 1;
         else
            new[i][j] = 0;
      }
   }

   return new;
}

void draw(int grid[MAX_Y][MAX_X]) {
   int i, j;
   
   for (i = 0; i < MAX_Y; ++i) {
      for (j = 0; j < MAX_X; ++j) {
         putchar((grid[i][j]) ? '#' : '.');
         /* printf("|%2d", grid[i][j]); */
      }
      putchar('\n');
   }
}

int main(void) {

   int map[MAX_Y][MAX_X];
   memset(map, 0, sizeof map);

   map[2][2] = 1;
   map[3][2] = 1;
   map[4][2] = 1;
   map[4][3] = 1;
   map[3][4] = 1;

   printf(  " Game of Life v1.0\n"
            "Press ENTER to step.\n");

   for (;;) {
      draw(map);
      memcpy(map, update(map), sizeof map);
      getchar();
   }
}
```

Comment: Your `update` function returns a dangling pointer, since the array is local to the function and goes out of scope when it ends

Comment: `if (dsty > 0 ...)` ==> `if (dsty >= 0 ...)` and for x.